# MVC for image rendering - Specifically in python (PIL or Pillow)

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

Separation of concerns is important for making code maintainable. Anybody aware of already built frameworks that implement perhaps an MVC approach for image rendering with for example [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (or [pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/))

It is probably not too hard to come up with such a framework, but any existing best practices would help navigate the waters of repeating mistakes, etc.

Edit: To be clear, my request is regarding creating a new image by combining and overlaying other images. Perhaps the analogy can be a framework like [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) which uses models to generate html pages ... similarly this framework or architecture would allow for generating dynamic png's from a dynamic dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a resource that provides many examples of server-side image resizing.

https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js/wiki/Server-Resizing-Images

I'm not sure if any of them would meet the needs of your project as is, but I'm sure there's some take aways from their implementations that you can apply to your own project.

Comment: resizing is a slightly simpler problem. I was more asking from a photo creation point of view. Like creating a report or a dynamic image based on combining and overlaying images.